# Using javascript, how can I write a function that will proportionally increase/decrease the size of a rectangle based on its width

Tags: javascript

I want to increase a rectangle's size proportionally.

Each time I increase the x axis,  the y axis should increase proportionally.

Consindering a rectangle with the dimension of x = 500, y = 200

I want increase the x axis to 800.

How should I work out what the new y axis should be to keep the proportion correct?

Also I would like to reduce the x axis and proportionally reduce the y.

Comment: calculate the initial ratio of x:y and y:x, and depending on your axis-change you need to use one of those ratios to calculate the other axis ...

Comment: Failed? Maybe you can show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Rectangle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Rectangle.prototype.scale = function (arg) {
    if (arg.x) {
        return new Rectangle(arg.x, this.y * arg.x / this.x);
    } else {
        return new Rectangle(this.x * arg.y / this.y, arg.y);
    }
};

new Rectangle(500, 200).scale({ x: 800 })
// Rectangle {x: 800, y: 320}
```